# React Converting JSX application to Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

I am keeping my code short as possible to remove confusion, actually i am trying to convert my application built on React jsx to React Typescript thus (tsx file).

**Error** that i am receiving is - '[ts] Property '**state**' does not exist on type 'App'.any ALSO same for '[ts] Property '**setState**' does not exist on type 'App'.any' 
Please help me on this ...

```js
interface STATE {
  loading: boolean
};

interface PROPS {};

export default class App extends Component<STATE, PROPS> {
  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fruitsData : [],
      loading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });

    //Further functions present here plus call to service and binding the 
     data received to the array fruitsData
  }
```

My package.json

```js
 {

  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^4.0.35",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
    "typescript": "^2.7.0-insiders.20171214"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "react-search-box": "0.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  }
}
```

Comment: you did install @types for react and ReactDOM right?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier oops sorry not yet, both @types/react-dom & @types/react install are under progress

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure we have enough here to reproduce your issue. If you have the necessary modules installed, then I guess that the issue might come from TypeScript being incorrectly configured. Did you start from create-react-app? If so, there are guides on using it with TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must install `@types/{react packages}`. Then you have to import React like that: `import * as React from "react"`

Then your code would look like this:

```
interface IAppState {
  fruitsData: any[]; // change it for your type
  loading: boolean;
}

interface IAppProps {
  // your props
}

class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
  constructor(props: IAppProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fruitsData: [],
      loading: false,
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true;
    });
  }
}
```

or you can write it without constructor like this:

```
class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
  public state: IAppState = {
    fruitsData: [],
    loading: false,
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true;
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should ensure that the type definitions for `react` and `react-dom` are installed. With NPM you could do:

```
npm install --save @types/{react,react-dom}
```

Then there are a few problems with your code, which I have corrected inline:

```
interface State {
  loading: boolean
  // add fruitsData to state
  fruitsData: string[] // or whatever type it is
}

interface Props {}

// Generic arguments are <Props, State>, not the other way around
export default class App extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) { // use the correct type here
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fruitsData : [],
      loading: false
    };
  }
```

Comment: i tried this but still i am getting the same error.

But when i introduced **'public state: STATE;'** after export default class App extends Component<PROPS, STATE>{}.. Error is not there on **'this.state'** whereas on other side i am still getting the error **'[ts] Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'App'**

Comment: Yes i am importing it : "import React, { Component } from 'react' "

Comment: yes may be you are right but i made sure those are installed and present in package.json..actually after that also VSCode underlines them with same error ... i removed them by adding these two lines after Export default class App extends Component ..
**setState: any;
  public state: STATE;**

Comment: If you are correctly extending `React.Component<Props, State>` then `setState` and `state` will be defined for you, so I guess that there's something missing still.

Comment: Thanks - @TomFenech  for your help , i resolved the error by creating application again following NPM create-react-ts command :P

Answer (score 0):

You were placing generic type PROPS & STATES at wrong position.

The first one is Props and second one is State.

```js
export default class App extends Component<PROPS, STATE>
```

Comment: i tried this but still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1). run

`npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`

or

`yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`

2). Rename any file to be a TypeScript file (e.g. src/index.js to src/index.tsx)

3). Restart your development server!

enjoy :)